# Checking for maximum length of consecutive days which satisfy specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with the structure:

beverages_log(id, users_id, beverages_id, timestamp)

I'm trying to compute the maximum streak of consecutive days during which a user (with id 1) logs a beverage (with id 1) at least 5 times each day.  I'm pretty sure that this can be done using views as follows:

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW daycounts AS
SELECT count(*) AS n, DATE(timestamp) AS d FROM beverages_log
WHERE users_id = '1' AND beverages_id = 1 GROUP BY d;

CREATE or REPLACE VIEW t AS SELECT * FROM daycounts WHERE n >= 5;

SELECT MAX(streak) AS current FROM ( SELECT DATEDIFF(MIN(c.d), a.d)+1 AS streak
FROM t AS a LEFT JOIN t AS b ON a.d = ADDDATE(b.d,1)
LEFT JOIN t AS c ON a.d <= c.d
LEFT JOIN t AS d ON c.d = ADDDATE(d.d,-1)
WHERE b.d IS NULL AND c.d IS NOT NULL AND d.d IS NULL GROUP BY a.d) allstreaks;
```

However, repeatedly creating views for different users every time I run this check seems pretty inefficient.  Is there a way in MySQL to perform this computation in a single query, without creating views or repeatedly calling the same subqueries a bunch of times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution seems to perform quite well as long as there is a composite index on users_id and beverages_id -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, IF(@prev + INTERVAL 1 DAY = t.d, @c := @c + 1, @c := 1) AS streak, @prev := t.d
    FROM (
        SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS d, COUNT(*) AS n
        FROM beverages_log
        WHERE users_id = 1
        AND beverages_id = 1
        GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
    ) AS t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @c := 1) AS vars
) AS t
ORDER BY streak DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yep, this works well - thanks!  I'm not sure I fully understand the "INNER JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @c := 1) AS vars" - is this just to clear the variables?

Comment: It is just to make sure they don't have any values from a previous run of the query.

Comment: Gotcha.  One more question - how is it that @prev is actually referring to the date for the previous row?  It seems that if it's defined as "@prev := t.d", it'll just give the date for the current row.

Comment: It works because streak is evaluated before @prev is re-assigned. There is a warning in the [Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) that this order of evaluation should not be relied upon but it is widely used and unlikely to change.

Answer (score 0):

Why not include user_id in they daycounts view and group by user_id and date.

Also include user_id in view t.

Then when you are queering against t add the user_id to the where clause.

Then you don't have to recreate your views for every single user you just need to remember to include in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

That's a little tricky.  I'd start with a view to summarize events by day:

```
CREATE VIEW BView AS
    SELECT UserID, BevID, CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE) AS EventDate, COUNT(*) AS NumEvents
    FROM beverages_log
    GROUP BY UserID, BevID, CAST(EventDateTime AS DATE)
```

I'd then use a Dates table (just a table with one row per day; very handy to have) to examine all possible date ranges and throw out any with a gap.  This will probably be slow as hell, but it's a start:

```
SELECT
    UserID, BevID, MAX(StreakLength) AS StreakLength
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        B1.UserID, B1.BevID, B1.EventDate AS StreakStart, DATEDIFF(DD, StartDate.Date, EndDate.Date) AS StreakLength
    FROM
        BView AS B1
        INNER JOIN Dates AS StartDate ON B1.EventDate = StartDate.Date
        INNER JOIN Dates AS EndDate ON EndDate.Date > StartDate.Date
    WHERE
            B1.NumEvents >= 5
        -- Exclude this potential streak if there's a day with no activity
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Dates AS MissedDay WHERE MissedDay.Date > StartDate.Date AND MissedDay.Date <= EndDate.Date AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BView AS B2 WHERE B1.UserID = B2.UserID AND B1.BevID = B2.BevID AND MissedDay.Date = B2.EventDate))
        -- Exclude this potential streak if there's a day with less than five events
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BView AS B2 WHERE B1.UserID = B2.UserID AND B1.BevID = B2.BevID AND B2.EventDate > StartDate.Date AND B2.EventDate <= EndDate.Date AND B2.NumEvents < 5)
    ) AS X
GROUP BY
    UserID, BevID
```

Comment: As written, this counts 04/02 to 04/04 as a two-day streak, because the difference of the dates is two.  If you think of this as three days, just add one.  Actually using `COUNT(*)` rather than `DATEDIFF()` should give that result, too.