# Figuring out a maximum streak (number) of consecutive days

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a simple table containing a date or datetime column, I'd like to query the maximum streak of consecutive days during which rows exist, given optional filters.

e.g. say a table has the following columns:

> id, datetime, username, category

I'd like to be able to query, in the most efficient way possible, the:

- longest streak (in days) of a given username,
- longest streak (in days) of a given username within a given category,
- longest streak (in days) regardless of any username or category,
- etc.

(I guess the query wouldn't change much based on these filters, but they give an idea.)

Found other similar questions but none seemed to answer this particular need, however feel free to link me to an appropriate one which I may have missed.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do you want to have the largest number of consecutive days a given user has been recorded (hard) or the largest number of days between two consecutives logins (easy) ?

Comment: The former. And I do realize the query isn't going to be straightforward... Thank you.

Comment: this will be structured as a LAG query that calculates the difference between this rows data and the previous row.  then that should generate a value of '1' if less than a day.  that whole thing is a subquery for a cumulative sum that resets on a non-1 row. - then that is the subquery for a MAX aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end the answer was pretty much the same as that of the existing question: [Checking for maximum length of consecutive days which satisfy specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020540/checking-for-maximum-length-of-consecutive-days-which-satisfy-specific-condition?rq=1).

However I rewrote it for more clarity and adjusted a few things:

```
SELECT streak
FROM (
    SELECT IF(@prevDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY = current.date, @currentStreak := @currentStreak + 1, @currentStreak := 1) AS streak, @prevDate := current.date
    FROM (
        SELECT DATE(datetime) AS date
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date
    ) AS current
    INNER JOIN (SELECT @prevDate := NULL, @currentStreak := 1) AS vars
) AS _
ORDER BY streak DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Marking this question as duplicate seems right in the end though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT streak
FROM (
    SELECT tb.*, IF(@prev + INTERVAL 1 DAY = tb.d, @count := @count + 1, @count := 1) AS streak, @prev := tb.d
    FROM (
        SELECT datetime AS d
        FROM sometable
        WHERE username = "PWET"
        ORDER BY datetime
    ) AS tb
    INNER JOIN (SELECT @prev := NULL, @count := 1) AS vars
) AS tb
ORDER BY streak DESC LIMIT 1;
```

source: [Checking for maximum length of consecutive days which satisfy specific condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020540/checking-for-maximum-length-of-consecutive-days-which-satisfy-specific-condition?rq=1)

Comment: Oh this seems to be the picked answer from the first "related" question, I came across it but for some reason thought the case I had was not exactly the same. It seems to be working but I can't try it before a few hours, thank you though!

Comment: Your case was not exactly the same, but it bears very strong resemblance. Let me know if you find any typo, I haven't had the chance to test it from here.

Comment: Actually, the COUNT/GROUP BY of the query was necessary, and I made another couple adjustments. I'll post it as answer myself and mark it as duplicate. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: After taking the time to rewrite the query (see the answer), COUNT does not make sense in this case (e.g. it's useless), and GROUP BY is just here to optimize the query so as not to check the same date several times in a row.

Comment: I have actually missed the `ORDER BY` clause, but do you have several entry for a given user at a given day ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, hence the GROUP BY. I think ORDER BY was omitted from the original answer due to GROUP BY seemingly ordering by itself in the process, but I read this is not 100% guaranteed behavior so added it too.